# How to fix error in MIT Kerberos Ticket Initialization failed. Error 22

Tags: tableau-api, mit-kerberos

Hi I am currently trying to connect my Tableau Platform to my database and I am currently going through installing the Kerberos client. I have pasted the correct krb5.ini within my c:\programdata\MIT folder and also added a new variable within my extension variables but the problem I have is that I am unable to get a ticket using my username and password.

Currently I get the following error:

```
Ticket initialization failed. Kerberos 5: Invalid argument (error 22)
```

I have searched google but haven't come across anything that identifies this error so would really appreciate if somebody could please advise on where I am going wrong or even what the error means.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see the kinit command your using?  Can we also see the krb5.ini?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks T Heron for your response. I have now managed to fix this issue. What I did was uninstall Kerberos version 4.1 as a colleague mentioned that they have been known issues with this version so I then installed the previous version 4.0.1 and I am now able to get a ticket and connect to Tableau as required.

Thanks once again for your time.